# How to hide a TextView when the user is logged in

Tags: java, android, textview

This is my task: When a user is logged in, The `TextView` **will be invisible** in my Activity. I'm using : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

And here is my code:

```
if (session.isLoggedIn()) 
{
      sgnin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //sgnin is my TextView i need to Invisible it.    
}
```

Actual and General statement in tutorial:

```
if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
    logoutUser();
}
```

But after doing this, method ; `setVisibility` doesnt work!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you run `setVisibility` before `logoutUser`?

Comment: Because i need to user logged in and then after saving the user credentials, that `TextView` will be invisible

Comment: Just because the visibilty is invisible it doesn't mean that the TextView isn't there. It is and will contain the value you need

Comment: @cjds - i know that, so, i need to when user is logged in, that `Sign in button` will be `invisible`.what is wrong i can't figured out!

Comment: if `sgnin` is TextView and that line is executed it has to work...

Comment: i can give you all those codes, should i do that for checking? i dont know whats the problem :-?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not making that call on the UI thread. Try this instead:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sgnin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    }        
});
```